# HTMLDivElement resizing inconsistent after WebpackDevServer build

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a custom web component that I am trying to make which looks like this
[image: Sample Image 1]
But it looks like this after I reload the page
[image: Sample Image 2]
Notice the thin white div at the very bottom of each image.

I notice that I get the desired result (the fist image) immediately following a Webpack build triggered by saving this component's javascript file. Each time I reload the page, the second image is rendered on screen. What causes this behavior? I will attach the pertinent parts of my code below. (The styling for the large yellow and white components is done for privacy)

FeaturedProjectCard.js

```
const template = document.createElement('template')
template.innerHTML = `
    <style>
        .bottomDivider {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 75%;
            height: 1px;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: white;
        }
        .container {
            position: relative;
            width: 1000px;
            isolation: isolate;
        }
        .description {
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 25px;
            color: white;
            background-color: white;
        }
        .linksContainer {
            display: flex;
        }
        .linksContainer > a {
            width: 20px;
            padding: 10px;
            color: white;
            transition: color 0.5s;
        }
        .linksContainer > a:first-child {
            padding-left: 0;
        }
        .linksContainer > a:hover {
            color: yellow;
        }
        .projDesc {
            width: 50%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        .projDesc > * {
            width: fit-content;
            pointer-events: auto;
        }
        .projImage {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            right: 0;
            height: 300px;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            background-color: yellow;
            border-radius: 5px;
            z-index: -1;
        }
        .projImage > img {
            height: inherit;
            border-radius: inherit;
            filter: grayscale(100%);
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 0.5s, filter 0.5s, -webkit-filter 0.5s;
        }
        .projImage > img:hover {
            opacity: 1;
            filter: grayscale(0%);
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
        }
        .projectHeading {
            margin: 10px 0;
            color: yellow;
            font-size: 12pt;
        }
        .projectName {
            display: inline;
            margin: 15px 0;
            font-size: 21pt;
            color: white;
        }
        .softwareContainer {
            margin: 25px 0 10px 0;
            color: white;
        }
        .softwareContainer > span:not(:last-child) {
            padding-right: 30px;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="projDesc">
            <span class="projectHeading">Recent Project</span>
            <span class="projectName"></span>
            <div class="description"></div>
            <div class="softwareContainer"></div>
            <div class="linksContainer"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="projImage">
            <img>
        </div>
        <p class="bottomDivider"></p>
    </div>
`

class FeaturedProjectCard extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super()
        
        //Enable shadow DOM
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true))
        
        //Insert project image
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('img').src = this.getAttribute('image')

        //Insert project heading
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.projectName').textContent = this.getAttribute('heading')
        
        //Insert project description
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.description').innerHTML = //Get description text
        
        //Insert software array
        const softwareItems = //Get items
        if(softwareItems) {
            const softwareContainer = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.softwareContainer')
            for(let i = 0; i < softwareItems.length; i++)
                softwareContainer.innerHTML += `<span>${softwareItems[i].textContent}</span>`
        }

        //Insert link array
        const links = //Get links
        if(links) {
            const linksContainer = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.linksContainer')
            for(let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                linksContainer.innerHTML += `<a target="_blank" href="${links[i].getAttribute('target')}">${links[i].innerHTML}</a>`
            }
        }

        //Handle reverse attribute
        if(this.hasAttribute('reversed')) {
            this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.bottomDivider').style.right = 0;
            this.shadowRoot.lastElementChild.style.height = `${this.shadowRoot.lastElementChild.offsetHeight}px`
            const projDesc = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.projDesc')
            const projImage = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.projImage')
            const softwareItems = Array.from(this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.softwareContainer > span'))
            projDesc.style.position = 'absolute'
            projDesc.style.right = '0'
            projDesc.style.left = 'auto'
            projImage.style.left = '0'
            projImage.style.right = 'auto'
            projDesc.style.alignItems = 'flex-end'
            softwareItems.splice(0, 1)[0].style.padding = '0'
            const padding = getComputedStyle(softwareItems[0]).getPropertyValue('padding-right')
            softwareItems.forEach(item => {
                item.style.paddingLeft = padding
                item.style.paddingRight = '0'
            })
        }

        //Clear markup
        this.innerHTML = null
    }

}

window.customElements.define('featured-project-card', FeaturedProjectCard)
```

I use these component in HTML with the following syntax.

`<featured-project-card class="" reversed image="/something.png" heading="Heading">`

I think that the root cause of this behavior is the inclusion of the optional 'reversed' attribute. The other components that don't use this attribute are not affected by this issue since `div.projDesc` has `position: static` for those instances. This allows the `div.container` to resize. These images show the only component where this attribute is used. I will end this post with one final image of a component without the 'reversed' attribute for reference. In essence, I achieve the reverse effect by setting the `div.projDesc` properties `position`, `right`, and `left` to `absolute`, `0`, and `auto` respectively. Consequently, I had to set the `div.container` height equal to what it was prior to these changes. Otherwise the element would not size correcly since `position: absolute` is being used on the only child with `position: static`
I used a ResizeObserver to see if the `div.projDesc` was resizing itself more than once and indeed it was. To wrap up, the 'reversed' `div.projDesc` is resizing itself strangely (likely because of how the 'reverse' attribute is handled) as opposed to non 'reversed' elements. I am aware that there may be an easier way to solve this problem and I am open to suggestions, however, I would like to pin down the source of this behavior in hopes of gaining a better understanding of the nuances of HTML, CSS, & JS. I am more than happy to clarify myself for anyone that is willing to lend a hand. Thank you in advance!

Non reversed component
[image: Sample Image 3]

Comment: Remove all absolute positioning in your component, you don't need them here. It will only lead to errors (like you described) Also for "reverse" no absolute positioning is necessary. Don't use `<p>` to create borders, use border or :after from CSS. Use flexbox (or grid) to get your layout.

Comment: Thank you for commenting! I am currently in the process of converting to a flex layout. I think it will shorten my code a good bit. I completely forgot about the pseudo-elements I think I'll also include that. Thanks once again for lending a hand.